# Getting precision of a float in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, floating-point, decimal

Let's say I had a Perl variable:

`my $string = "40.23";`

`my $convert_to_num = $string * 1;`

Is there a way I can find the precision of this float value? My solution so far was to simply just loop through the string, find the first instance of '.', and just start counting how many decimal places, returning 2 in this case. I'm just wondering if there was a more elegant or built-in function for this sort of thing. Thanks!

Comment: Down this path lies madness. Assigning a decimal precision to the floating point representation of a number is futile except in a few special cases. Execute this code and reconsider your question: `perl -e 'printf "%.*f\n", $_, "40.23" for 14,15,41'`

Comment: I wasn't able to run that code without errors?

Comment: As I read the question, the problem is not to calculate the number of decimal places from the value stored as a float or a BigFloat but rather the calculate how many digits appear after the decimal point in the input numeral. That is, a string has been read, and the question is a matter of string processing, not a numerical calculation. Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly it yes. I was just wondering if there was a built in function or standard solution to return how many decimal places in a number and/or string. I couldn't  find anything after researching and my proposed solution above.

Comment: What does precision have to do with number of decimal places?

Comment: The precision of 40.23 is 4, no?

Comment: My mistake, I mixed up my definitions. I just meant the # of decimal places, not precision.

Comment: No, the precision of the floating point representation of 40.23 on a finite-precision machine is not 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer for "number of things after the period" in $nstring

```
length(($nstring =~ /\.(.*)/)[0]);
```

The matching part first finds . (\.), then matches everything else (.*). Since .* is in parentheses, it is returned as the first array element ([0]). Then I count how many with the length() function.

Answer (score 3):

Anything you do in Perl with plain variables will be dependent on the compiler and hardware you use. If you really care about the precision, use

```
use "Math::BigFloat";
```

And set the desired properties. The number of digits is more properly termed accuracy in Math::BigFloat.

```
use Math::BigFloat;

Math::BigFloat->accuracy(12);
$n = new Math::BigFloat "52.12";

print "Accuracy of $n is ", $n->accuracy(), " length ",scalar($n->length()),"\n";
```

Will return

```
Accuracy of 52.1200000000 is 12 length 4
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't set it. I'm reading from cells in an Excel spreadsheet and only want to read what is in the spreadsheet, not set my own global limit.

Comment: What prevents you from reading your spreadsheet values in and storing them internally as big-floats?  I think it's up to the programmer how to treat data he receives from an external source.

Comment: Right, I agree, and I am doing that. But one of the fields I also need to store is how many decimal places there are.

Comment: The length() operator tells how many numbers there are. (In this case, 4)